# PHP Displaying data from MySQL database

Tags: php

I wanted to display a page content with PHP and MySQL. But i don't know how to select and display data from PHP.

```
$name = $_GET['title'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = $name";
$result = mysql_query("$query");
```

But i don't know how to display data. I want to get the string value from `content` in sql table row where `name = $name` and display it.

If you can, please help me

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Please refer to this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @JitendraKhatri Avoid w3schools, go straight to PHP documentation for specific functions

Comment: **first :** dont use `mysql_`, use `mysqli_` instead... **second**, search for `mysqli_fetch_array`

Answer (score 1):

You may try and include this in your code:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = $name";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['content'];
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Here I have assumed `$link` as the handle to connect to the database.

**N.B.:** You may consider passing the `$_GET` values through `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to avoid sql injections which may prove fatal to the database and its tables. You also need to consider the usage of `mysqli_*` functions because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be discontinued.

Comment: @Mg112: I hope don't mind... if you consider this answer to be the best one, I humbly request you to please mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your sql, change

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = $name";
$result = mysql_query("$query");
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = '".$name."'";  // as name is char it should be enclosed in quotes
$result = mysql_query($query);   // using quotes inside this will just display it without executing the query
```

You can fetch the results by this (if the result is only single record):

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);   // fetch the result as an array with subscript as the field name

echo $row['content'];   // echo the value of the field content
```

If the query result contains multiple records then you have to do this inside a while loop like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))   // fetch the result as an array with subscript as the field name
{
    echo $row['content'];   // echo the value of the field content
}
```

Comment: Don't use mysql statements, these are deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = $name");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

//you'll get value in var
$var=$result['content'];
```

Comment: Don't use mysql statements, these are deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this

```
$name = $_GET['title'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = '".$name."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//get values returned from query
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

//display required content
echo $row['content'];
```

Also `mysql_*` function are deprecated.You have to stop using this. Start using `PDO` or `prepared statements` or `mysqli_*` function

Comment: Don't use mysql statements, these are deprecated!

Comment: @user2019515 I know that thats what i have advised him

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `mysql_` is deprecated, use `mysqli_`

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

/* associative array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this using Prepared Statements :**

```
$query = "SELECT whatever1, whatever2 FROM pages WHERE name = ?";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($value_you_want, $value_you_want_as_well);
while($stmt->fetch()){
echo $value_you_want . $value_you_want_as_well;
}
$stmt->close();
```

**Or you can do this using PDO :**

```
$query = "SELECT whatever1, whatever2 FROM pages WHERE name = :name";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $page) {
    echo $page->whatever1 . $page->whatever2;
}
$stmt = null; // Set to null to destroy connection
```